# Deeplink on Flutter, interact with backend

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

I have deeplink on my Flutter app. When open deeplink on device not install the app, it show error page, it make poor UX.

I saw some another app, when open deeplink on device not install the app, it show a download page or the content of deeplink but on website, not the empty not found page. Sometime, the web have button 'Open "something" in app' and it directly open app without yes no popup.

How to do it with my backend on my company, i mean, how to build the good architecture to implement a whole deeplink problem of a business app that have a website, a backend and a mobile app.
Sorry for my English :(